# Set ActionBar tab divider and selector color

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, selector

I want to set the ActionBar divider and selector Color. How can I do that?

I tried that but it didn't work:

```
<style name="MyActionBar.ActionBar.TabBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/ConnectMe</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>

</style>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per discussion **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010803/android-action-bar-tab-bar-divider)**, set the attribute `android:actionBarDivider` immediate under the Custom Theme tag/definition. Try this -

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@drawable/tab_divider</item>
</style>
```